# Revert to unnamed namespace after importing another namespace within same scope

Tags: c++, namespaces, unnamed-namespace

I have the following code from a textbook:

```
namespace sally {
    void message( ) {
        std::cout << "Hello from Sally.\n";
    }
} 

namespace {
    void message( ) {
        std::cout << "Hello from unnamed.\n";
    }
}

int main( ) {
    message(); 
    {
        message( );
        using sally::message;
        message( );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The code `using sally::message;` changes the default call to the function `message()` to be the call from the namespace `sally`. If I wanted to call `message()` from the unnamed namespace, I do know that I can use `::message()`.

But is it possible to change the default call to `message()` (within the scope) back to the function from the unnamed namespace?

Comment: Wow, I've never even considered wanting to do that! Are you asking only out of curiosity? I hope so, because otherwise it's a terrible idea. Pretty sure the answer is no. You have imported a namespace into that scope. You cannot "un-import" it. Use block scope to control that, if you must.

Comment: Related to Paddy's comment above: Changing the scope ( https://godbolt.org/z/WE8bocsha ) is about the best you can do while still producing what I'd consider readable code.

Comment: You can isolate that "default" by using yet another scope block: `{ using sally::message; message( ); }`

Answer (score 1):

You can bring in `(anonymous)::message` seperately with `using ::message;`:

```cpp
int main( ) {
    message(); 
    {
        message( );
        using sally::message;
        message( );
        {
            using ::message;
            message( );  // Lookup finds `::message` (introduced above) and stops looking in outer block scopes
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It has to be in a new block scope because if it was in the same scope, `message()` would be ambiguous.